# ¿Por qué se denomina "la niña bonita" al número quince"?

Tags: modismos, definiciones, locuciones, dle, números

El [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/ni%C3%B1o?m=form2#8TpD7M6) define **la niña bonita** como

> 1. f. Especialmente en los sorteos, **número quince**.

¿Cuál es el origen de este modismo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Versión larga**

Desde el S. XIX y XX se ha desarrollado en el mundo del juego y del azar una relación entre números y nombres. La exposición e irrupción progresiva de determinadas loterías y juegos en la sociedad ha hecho que esta relacione, **a veces de forma caprichosa y otras atendiendo a metáforas**, algunos números con nombres, de esta forma en algunos lugares del **sureste español** aún se puede escuchar en la venta ambulante de alguna lotería, por ejemplo en la ONCE (iguales), cantar al vendedor el nombre del número, en este caso, "llevo la niña bonita, la niña bonita" para referirse al número 15.

[image]

Esta relación entre números y nombres es desigual según las zonas y juegos, aunque muchos de estos nombres suelen repetirse u ocupar distinta posición en la tabla.

[image]

[image]

El hecho es que algunas asociaciones, entre números y nombres, igualmente se han extendido a otros juegos de azar como el bingo.

[image]

Los significados de los números del Bingo

*15 - La niña bonita: a los 15 años, antiguamente las niñas dejaban atrás la infancia y se convierten en mujeres*.

Como se ha dicho al comienzo de la cuestión, esta asociación de ideas **se encuentra relacionada tanto de forma caprichosa como por atender a distintas metáforas** y por tanto, esto implica que algunas relaciones son entendidas mejor que otras.

Así en algunos juegos el número 13, más familiar en general, se interpreta de forma negativa, asemejándolo con la mala suerte, mientras que en otras tablas aparece asociado con otros aspectos, el número 7, normalmente es el de la buena suerte, aunque en otras tablas aparece como la luna, asemejando a la luna recortada, el 22 con los patitos, el número 60 y 90 esta relacionado con una persona mayor "abuela y abuelo" y el último número el 100 se asocia con la muerte.

En el caso del número 15, la tradición generalmente ha relacionado el número con la juventud, y el cumplir los quince años (quinceañero/a) con el inicio de una nueva etapa de la vida, de ahí el nombre para este número "**niña bonita**", relacionado con lo que suponía el inicio de lo que se considera  juventud (14/15-23/24 años, depende de la madurez) y el hecho de dejar de ser niña para convertirse en mujer.

Igualmente puede que también ayudara a calar o expandir la idea y la relación número-nombre con el 15 la Zarzuela, "**La niña bonita**" (De Manuel Fernández Caballero, Luis Mariano de Larra), los estudiantes al inicio con los juegos de azar, el apodo a esa chica bella y "*niña enamorada*", que es la hija más pequeña de tres hermanos y la intriga de sus pretendientes.

En el caso de la lista de Almería, el número 15 es "uva", quizás referida a la "uva pasa", en el sentido del paso mismo de esa juventud.

En cualquier caso, creo que en la versión corta la pregunta quedaba en líneas generales contestada, se trataba de una relación antigua en la que llegar a cumplir los 15 años suponía para la niña convertirse en mujer, es decir, se relacionaba con la juventud, al igual que simplemente relacionamos el 13 con la mala suerte o el 22 con los patitos.

Comment: Me parece que Diego ha respondido correctamente la pregunta. "Niña bonita", según lo explicado, sería una niña que, devenida en mujer, merece ese calificativo.

Comment: Hola @Ananias, todo lo que he podido leer sobre el nº15 y su relación con numerología me apuntan a que el nº15 es símbolo de transición, de cambio, de renovación o paso hacia una experiencia nueva. Desde el libro de los "Números", dentro del Pentateuco, el capitulo 15, hablando de Moisés y el paso del pueblo de Dios hacia la tierra prometida y de sus celebraciones, sacrificios y ofrendas cuando lleguen a ella, hasta la relación entre "la niña de mis ojos" con "la niña bonita" como periodos de transformación o ruptura pues a veces se interpreta a modo del personaje de "lolita" de los 50 'y 60'.

Comment: Así que una vez más aparece en el común la imagen de mudanza que supone el 15 y la relación con las mujeres que alcanzan o están alrededor de esa edad. Antonio Machado de 34 años se caso con Leonor de 15 años. En la antigüedad fue más común ver casamientos a edad temprana. La misma Zarzuela, "La niña Bonita", es de 1881, en ella se aprecia la conexión entre esa juventud y el paso, o necesidad, hacia el casamiento. Cecilia, la hija menor, no dice su edad, calculo que tendría entre 15 y 17 años a lo sumo. La hermana mayor 30, el hijo 27 y Cecilia le lleva bastante más de 10 años a la mayor.

Comment: El 22 se relaciona con dos patitos, el 11 con dos banderillas o dos soldados, el 13 con la mala suerte, por ser la traición a Jesús en la última cena, el 15 con la transición, renovación, cambio o metamorfosis, el 33 con la muerte de Cristo... Gracias por ahondar en el tema.